# filter on containable in CakePHP 3

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.4

I'm using CakePHP 3.4+

I have following tables and their association.

**PostVideos**->belongsTo(**Campaigns**) || **PostVideos** has column **campaign_id**

**Campaigns**->hasMany(**ClientCampaigns**) || **ClientCampaigns** has column **campaign_id**

**UserClients**->hasMany(**ClientCampaigns**) || **ClientCampaigns** has coumn **user_client_id**

**UserClients** has column **client_id**

I want to **select/count** on **PostVideos** with condition on **client_id** in **UserClients**

```
$count['videos']['uploaded'] = $this->Campaigns->PostVideos->find()
    ->where(['UserClients.client_id' => $this->Auth->user('id')])
    ->contain(['Campaigns.ClientCampaigns.UserClients'])
    ->count();
```

**But it gives Database error as**

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'UserClients.client_id' in 'where clause'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `matching` for that

```
$userId=$this-Auth->user('id');
$this->Campaigns->PostVideos->find()
     ->matching('Campaings.ClientCampaings.UserClients',function(Query $query) use ($userId) {
         return $query->where(['UserClients.client_id' => $userId])
      }
    ->contain(['Campaigns.ClientCampaigns.UserClients'])
    ->count();
```

If you dont need to load `UserClients` you can skip `contain`.